# Spree Commerce - "Bundle install" (replace my files and lose info)

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, bundle, spree, commerce

I am working on a e-commerce platform with Spree Commerce (RoR), each time I run

```
bundle install
```

command (after add a new gem), Spree change all my website (app)!!
I don't know why but Spree replace all my view, models and controllers files, ... it make me start all over again...

At first, I used to replace them with my backups, so far, I made so many modifications that I forget what files I've modified.

How can I disable the functionality to replace all my files?
Or any advise to work with it (install gems and stuff)

Thanks in advance

Comment: To solve that, I've executed my app in a production mode, so after install a new gem and then "bundle install", all my views and controllers have not changed. :)

Answer (score 0):

Do you use a DVCS as [git](http://git-scm.com/)? If not you should.

After `bundle install` which command do you are using?

Comment: I have only add the gems into Gemfile, then "bundle install", after that I used to reload the explorer... 
"Do you use a DVCS as git? If not you should." <------ I don't know what it is, I wil look for info about that.